# Xamarin Forms : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I keep getting this error, I have basically copied all the code from [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/datapages/getting-started/#loadtheme), so I Don't understand why it isn't working here.

```
 namespace BHASIVCBULLETIN1 {
        using System;
        using Xamarin.Forms;
        using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;


        public partial class App : global::Xamarin.Forms.Application {

            [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
            private void InitializeComponent() {
    -->           this.LoadFromXaml(typeof(App));
            }
        }
    }
```

Above is the error code, it is generated at runtime.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:ListDataPage   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Pages;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Pages" 
                  x:Class="BHASIVCBULLETIN1.LinkerPage"
                  Title="Sessions" StyleClass="Events">

 <p:ListDataPage.DataSource>
    <p:JsonDataSource Source="http://demo3143189.mockable.io/sessions" />
</p:ListDataPage.DataSource>
```

This is the linker pages code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms.Pages;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BHASIVCBULLETIN1
{
    public partial class LinkerPage : Xamarin.Forms.Pages.ListDataPage
    {
        public LinkerPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

This is my main app c# code

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace BHASIVCBULLETIN1 {
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LinkerPage());
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

}

This is my main app's xml code

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:mytheme="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Themes;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Dark" 
        x:Class="BHASIVCBULLETIN1.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
         <ResourceDictionary MergedWith="mytheme:DarkThemeResources" />
        <!-- above xml code rferences the datapages nuget packages and resources that allow the methods to be used to create the GUI-->
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue, and also followed the instructions explicitly.

It appears that:
    `<ResourceDictionary MergedWith="mytheme:DarkThemeResources"/>`
is failing in some way and leaves the App object undefined as a result.
I'm beginning to think this is a bug in Xamarin.Forms.Themes that needs to be resolved.  My understanding is it a "Pre release" version, so maybe it's still not reliable.

More...
I tested the themes feature with a NEW empty Xamarin forms project (VS2015) using the default references created by the Xamarin new empty cross platform template.  This references Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.forms.pages version 2.3.0.38-pre2 (in my case).  Themes work with these references.

After applying the latest Nuget updates to Forms and Pages (2.3.3.168) the Themes preview no longer works and reproduces the same error you indicate.  Seems to me that Xamarin.Forms.Themes simply doesn't behave with the latest released assemblies from Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a typo error but tag `<p:ListDataPage>` is not closed

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced app crashing with `Xamarin.Forms.Themes 1.0.0.43-pre1` after updating to `Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.168`.  This is only on Android so I am not sure if this problem is also happening on iOS or WP builds as well.  I upgraded from `Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.152-pre2` with which it was working just fine.

```
<prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Unity;assembly=Prism.Unity.Forms"
         xmlns:mytheme="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Themes;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Light"
         x:Class="myApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Xamarin.Forms.Themes 1.0.0.43-pre1 is broken with Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.168 -->
        <!--<ResourceDictionary MergedWith="mytheme:LightThemeResources">-->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- theme definitions -->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

My **solution** for now is to remove the `"MergedWith"` reference to the Xamarin.Forms.Theme until a fix is released.  Alternatively, roll back XF version to one compatible with the Themes package.